# Type variable introduction for existential types

Tags: haskell, existential-type, quantifiers, rank-n-types

Is there any binder in haskell to introduce a type variable (and constraints) quantified in a type ?

I can add an extra argument, but it defeats the purpose.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}


data Exists x = forall m. Monad m => Exists (m x)

convBad ::  x -> Exists x  
convBad  x = Exists @m (return @m x, undefined) --Not in scope: type variable ‘m’typecheck


data Proxy (m:: * -> *) where Proxy :: Proxy m

convOk ::  Monad m => x -> Proxy m -> Exists x 
convOk  x (_ :: Proxy m) = Exists (return @m x)
```

Comment: Why is `return @m x` more desirable here than, say, `return @Identity x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To bring type variables into scope, use `forall` (enabled by [`ExplicitForall`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/explicit_forall.html), which is implied by `ScopedTypeVariables`):

```
convWorksNow :: forall m x. Monad m => x -> Exists x  
convWorksNow x = Exists (return @m x)

-- Usage:
ex :: Exists Int
ex = convWorksNow @Maybe 42
```

But whether you do it like this or via `Proxy`, keep in mind that `m` must be chosen *at the point of creating `Exists`*. So whoever calls the `Exists` constructor must know what `m` is.

If you wanted it to be the other way around - i.e. whoever *unwraps* an `Exists` value chooses `m`, - then your `forall` should be on the inside:

```
newtype Exists x = Exists (forall m. Monad m => m x)

convInside :: x -> Exists x
convInside x = Exists (return x)

-- Usage:
ex :: Exists Int
ex = convInside 42

main = do
  case ex of
    Exists mx -> mx >>= print  -- Here I choose m ~ IO

  case ex of
    Exists mx -> print (fromMaybe 0 mx)  -- Here I choose m ~ Maybe
```

---

Also, as @dfeuer points out in the comments, note that your original type definition (the one with `forall` on the outside) is pretty much useless beyond just signifying the type of `x` (same as `Proxy` does). This is because whoever consumes such value must be able to work with *any* monad `m`, and you can do anything with a monad unless you know what it is. You can't bind it inside `IO`, because it's not necessarily `IO`, you can't pattern match it with `Just` or `Nothing` because it's not necessarily `Maybe`, and so on. The only thing you can do with it is bind it with `>>=`, but then you'll just get another instance of it, and you're back to square one.

Comment: Excellent answer, but the OP shouldn't need to add `ExplicitForAll` because [ScopedTypeVariables](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/scoped_type_variables.html) already implies it.

Comment: Thank you @RobinZigmond, I suspected as much, but couldn't find docs quickly.

Comment: `Exists` seems like an odd name for that `Forall` thing.

Comment: You might want to point out that the existential version is quite useless; `Exists x` is basically the same as `Proxy x`. The only time you might want an existential sort of like this is if you're using it to keep a value alive (for GC purposes), in which case you won't want the `Monad` constraint.

Comment: @dfeuer added an explanation

Comment: of course ! what was I thinking... ! I had an application in mind expressing a universal property (quantified over monads). I should revisit the application and repost.